# Inventory system approach

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

So I'm creating a system to control inventory. I have a text file which contains all the items in the inventory.

as:

```
{component, stock code, count, price}
```

I am creating a struct to represent the stock (this is done in a header file):

```
typedef struct StockItem {
    char *componentType;
    char *stockCode;
    int numOfItems
    int price;
} StockItem;
```

I want to have a struct in which controls the entire inventory as a linked list, was wondering how would I do it so it would have a collection of StockItems. ( would this be a good way to do it)?

Also one more question, is it conventional to have the struct as a capital letter or not ?

EDIT:

```
typedef struct inventory {
    struct StockItem item;
    struct inventory *next;
}inventory;

inventory *pFirstNode = NULL;
inventory *pLastNode = NULL;

void createNewList(struct StockItem *item){
    // Set aside enough space in memory for this struct

    inventory *pNewStruct = (inventory*) malloc(sizeof(inventory));

    // We can assign the value directly for the structs
    // reference for the next struct in the linked list
    pNewStruct->next = NULL;

    printf("Enter Product Name: ");

    // The & is needed only because scanf() is used
    pNewStruct->item = item;

    // When the first struct is created all of the following
    // refer to the same struct
    pFirstNode = pLastNode = pNewStruct;

}
```

Comment: put `int` members first, and leave the `char*` for the end. This will help with the struct's size and it's packing... it's current size is (variableByteNumber + 8). As for the convention - it's your code, ergo your convention. But since `struct` is a datatype, I'd prefer it to be lowercase :/

Comment: what within StockItem? why is this @Shark, I shall make it lowercase, my tutor does them in Capitals but every tutorial I have seen has been lower

Comment: Why is what? As for the capital letter - it's up to you. Your code, your convention. But since `struct` is not a class, no need to mix them while glancing over. However, you're very much free to do as your tutorials tell you, and consider changing your mind once you get in to a office ;)

Comment: Wow didn't know that! Thank you @Shark

Comment: There's just enough disinformation in this comment chain to be dangerous. The size of `char *` **is** known; It's the size of a *pointer*. To minimize padding in a structure the largest elements should generally be placed *first*, in order of the platform alignment requirements (largest + strictest alignment first). On a 64bit platform with 32bit native `int`, a pointer type *will* be larger than `int` and as such would ideally precede said-same in a struct. And the self-contradiction in the statement "... int's are always 4 bytes big because sizeof(int) is usually 4." - huh??

Comment: @WhozCraig jumps to the rescue, thanks man. Your pedantic expression is better than my ambiguousness, as I inferred that `sizeof(char*)` actually meant `the size of your string which is unknown at build-time` in that particular case. No problemo @session-start, just tryin to help out, sorry for misleading you a bit.

Comment: Its cool mate, I googled and filled in the gaps, you pointed me in the right direction @Shark

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If a linked list is suitable in your case really depends on how you want to access your inventory. If you plan only to go through it in sequence a linked list is good. If you store an index to a specific inventory item and later retrieve that item out of your list, thats going to be incredibly slow. In this case a datastructure with an array (std::vector for example) is better. But all of that also depends on the amount of data you have. Theres nothing wrong querying a linkedlist by index that only has 100 elements. For your specific question on how you can create a collection, are you limited to c, or can you use c++? The std namespace has a lot of useful collections including an implementation for a linkedlist and a vector which basically is an array, that dynamically resizes.

As you want to limit yourself to c, you will have to write your list implementation yourself. Its nothing that i would recommend somone who is still learning though. Implementing a decent list is really difficult. But if you really want to, [this](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) might be a good start. You also learn how linked lists work under the hood, which is a good thing considering a lot of people missuse linkedlists and wonder about bad performance afterwards.

Lets take the link above as an example. They defined a node struct:

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;
```

The field "val" is type int. In your case this will be the type of item, that you want to store in your list. Its going to be StockItem or a pointer to a StockItem, depending on how you want to manage your memory. If you want to add a StockItem to the list, you wrap it into a node and assign the pointer to that node to the "next" field of the previous node. Everything is also really well explained in the link i provided.

What you got so far is fine. Next, to add a node to your list, you should set the lastNode pointer and the next pointer in lastNode:

```
pLastNode->next = pNewStruct;
pLastNode = pNewStruct;
```

Comment: A simple HashMap that uses `stockCode` for a Key might be useful as well.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, also I understand Linkedlists and have created LinkedLists in C already, thats no the problem. The problem is actually creating the linked list so it contains the stock items. Would I pass the struct or something similar?

Comment: Sry misunderstood your code, edited my answer. Your doing fine!

Comment: I have inventory *myInv = createNewList(item); which creates the new list, how do I print out specifics within that list? such.. printf("%s", myInv->item->componentType); @MarioDekena

Comment: The code prints the componentType of the first item. If you have added more items, you have to loop through your list from the start or end. This is also covered in my link. Section "Iterating over a list".